# PostgreSQL Join Types

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

A homework question asked me to list all possible join types in PostreSQL.

My answer:

- INNER JOIN
- LEFT OUTER JOIN
- RIGHT OUTER JOIN
- FULL OUTER JOIN
- CROSS JOIN

with all its NATURAL variants (NATURAL INNER JOIN, NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN, ...).

However, the professor told us that there exists one more JOIN type. In my 2 years of working with SQL I have never seen any other JOIN types than these.

What are other JOIN types?

Comment: There are things called anti-joins, although they are not handled using the `JOIN` keyword.

Comment: The `UNION JOIN` was part of the SQL Standard until 2003. Afaik PostgreSQL never implemented it, though.

Comment: What about `LATERAL JOIN`s? See [7.2.1.5 Lateral Subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html)

Comment: This is not clear.--What does "join type" mean? Is a comma/implicit join a different "type" of JOIN from CROSS JOIN? Are joins without OUTER distinct "types" of join? Are inner joins with ON vs USING 2 different "types"? Does LATERAL give a different "type"? It's a bit much to interpret a join expression using LATERAL as a different type of join. LATERAL is a keyword that a DBMS can require when certain names appear in certain subexpressions. It could have been left out of the language with DBMSs required to handle all cases. The cases that require LATERAL interpret names in the obvious way.

Comment: No, it is not clear to anyone, and if you can't clearly say what you mean then it's not clear to you either. Look at the comments & the answers--"your professor might be"--"Lateral joins are not a different join type". Nobody knows what you mean, they are guessing. It seems that you are just hoping that there is some commonly understood thing that your professor & others use it for or would all use it for. There isn't.

Comment: Getting an answer doesn't mean the question was good, and again, it was not clear, and asking for guesses at reading your professor's mind is not a good question. Also my comments are clearly trying to help you. [ask] [help] I'm done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your professor might be relating to `LATERAL JOIN`s. That's actually a kind of subquery, that is introduced in the `FROM` clause.

There is a variety of lateral joins:

- `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`
- `INNER JOIN LATERAL`
- `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`

For more information, you can see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL).

Answer (score 2):

Lateral joins are not a different join type. Bot there are two more join types in PostgreSQL: semi-joins and anti-joins.

You cannot explicitly specify those join types, but the optimizer can transform subqueries in `IN` and `EXISTS` conditions into semi-joins and `NOT EXISTS` into an anti-join.

You can see these join types in `EXPLAIN` output.